# Undefined reference to not used class template method

Tags: c++, templates

In general, templates are implemented in the header files (as many answers in Stack Overflow point out) so the code template is available to the compiler when it needs it to create a new instance of the class/function. However, in my case, some of the methods in my template class can be used only for a certain type, so my class looks like:

**Class header**

```
#ifndef LEC_H
#define LEC_H

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class LEC
{
public:
  LEC()
  {
  }

  void func() const;

  void func2() const
  {
    std::cout << "Func 2" << std::endl;
  }
};

#endif  // LEC_H
```

**Class cpp**

```
#include "lec.h"

template <typename T>
void LEC<T>::func() const
{
  std::cout << "Func: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

template class LEC<float>;
template class LEC<double>;
```

The last two lines of the cpp file allow me to use `func()` because I explicitly instantiate this class template for these two types. When I use this class template in a program I can use any type as long as I do not call `func()`:

```
#include "lec.h"

int main()
{
  LEC<float> a;
  LEC<double> b;
  a.func2();
  a.func();
  b.func2();
  b.func();
  LEC<char> c;
  c.func2();
  return 0;
}
```

But, since the code is not available for the compiler to intsantiate `func()` for a `LEC` class with type `char`, I cannot do `c.func()` or I will get a compiler error:

> undefined reference to `LEC::func() const'

This is a simplification of my real code. However, in my code, when I do `LEC<char> c` to create an instance of the class I get the error, without calling any methods, only by constructing the class.

- Any idea on how to find out why this, apparently not used method, has to be linked anyways?
- Is there a way so the compiler (in my case I am using clang++: clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2) points out where is this method used within the code?
- Otherwise, can somebody explain why this (not having to link to a non-used class method) is working in the provided example and not in my code?

**Edit**
The cmake looks like:

```
add_library(lec_lib SHARED lec.cpp lec.h)
add_executable(lec_main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lec_main lec_lib)
```

Hence, the compiled library is linked with the executable.

**Edit 2**
Please avoid suggesting answers such as [Why templates can only be implemented in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) since I already know that the template has to be available to the compiler when the class is instantiated for a new type. My question is different. Why can I instantiate a type for which not all the template implementations are available as long as I do not use the specific class methods for which the template implementation is not provided at instantiation time (in the example case `func()`)

**Edit 3**
Regarding the suggestion that this is a duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). Again my question is different. I am looking for answers on why in the example I can instantiate `LEC<char>` when `LEC<char>::func()` is not visible for the compiler when it compiles the main program. And inthe case that this cannot be done and `L3C<char>::func()` is required to be linked, how to find why the method linkage is required while it is not being used (which is what happens in my real code).

Comment: I will read again more carefully this post that you mention, but I think my question is different.

Comment: No, it's the same, you forgot to compile the two cpp files and link against the two object files.

Comment: Please, reconsider opening this question again. I've made it clear that it is different from the suggested duplicates.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the mentioned posts by any means. The OP is having the specific issue why his compiler is asking for the definition of a never-used function.

Comment: apalomer: It might be a policy of your specific compiler that it wants all members to be defined. With clang++, your files compile and work fine. Have you tried to implement func() in the header? If the code does not work for a specific template parameter, but it's never used, it might still compile.

Comment: @apalomer You don't call c.func() in your main(), which is where the failure occurs. With that added, it fails with both g++ and clang++ on my machine.  I'd say just don't do that.